# TextBox update in order from an array?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

How would I be able to make it so the TextBox updates in order based on the Array?

I have 5 and 10 in the 'prices' array, I want it to go to 5 and then 10 and so fourth, what's the most efficient way of doing this? Right now it picks a random number in the array.

```
const pricetext = document.getElementById('ctl00_cphPrice')
var prices = ["5", "10"]

function update() {
pricetext.value = prices[Math.floor(Math.random() * prices.length)];
}

update()
```

Comment: You can use for loop

Comment: Can you post hole code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a closure over the index and increment it after assigning and adjust to the length of the array.

```js
const
    pricetext = document.getElementById('ctl00_cphPrice'),
    prices = ["5", "10"],
    update = (index => () => {
        pricetext.value = prices[index++];
        index %= prices.length;
    })(0);

setInterval(update, 2000);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="ctl00_cphPrice" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through your array using the [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method:

```
let prices = ["5", "10"];
prices.forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(item); // will log 5, then 10, etc...
});
```

You can also do this with a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration).